# Explain generic type inconsistency

Tags: haskell, generics, ghc

I was trying to get data constructor name by value.
I found a solution [here](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/14sp-cs240h/slides/generic.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators,
    FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
import GHC.Generics
undef2 :: mi f p -> f p
undef2 _ = undefined
data Tt = Cc deriving (Show, Generic)
> conName $ undef2 (from Cc)
"Cc"
```

I thought that is all I need and tried to put code above in a class instance for D1.

```
>:t (from Cc)
from Cc
  :: D1
       ('MetaData "Tt" "Main" "main" 'False)
       (C1 ('MetaCons "Cc" 'PrefixI 'False) U1)
       x
```

I assumed that if "from Cc" is D1 then implementation for D1 should work.

```
class GDConstrName a where
  gname :: a x -> String

instance GDConstrName (D1 m x) where
  gname x = conName $ undef2 x
```

Compilation of snippet above fails:

```
Main.hs:37:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘t0 c0 f0’
      ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at Main.hs:36:10-30
      Expected type: t0 c0 f0 x1
        Actual type: x x1
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘undef2 x’
      In the expression: conName $ undef2 x
      In an equation for ‘gname’: gname x = conName $ undef2 x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: D1 m x x1 (bound at Main.hs:37:9)
        gname :: D1 m x x1 -> String (bound at Main.hs:37:3)
   |
37 |   gname x = conName $ undef2 x
```

So it is mystery for me why same code works (x = (from Cc)) in one case but fails in another.

I found a solution without conName at all but it looks like to weird and
much lower level.

```
instance (KnownSymbol dcn) => GDConstrName (D1 m (C1 ('MetaCons dcn p f) gg)) where
  gname x = symbolVal (undefined :: Proxy dcn)
```

I run Ghc 8.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Spelling a bit more the types and kinds, we have

```
undef2 :: forall {k} {mi :: (k -> Type) -> k -> Type} {f :: k -> Type} {p :: k}.  mi f p -> f p
```

and, for the `D1` type constructor

```
D1 :: forall {k}. Meta -> (k -> Type) -> k -> Type
```

In your instance

```
instance GDConstrName (D1 m x) where
  gname z = conName $ undef2 z
```

The `x` type has kind `k -> Type`, because it fits in the 2nd parameter of the `D1` type constructor.

So the instance is saying that "for every type of kind `Meta` and for every type constructor of kind `k -> Type`, here's an implementation of `gname`".

However, `undef2` requires more "structure" on its input type. `mi` has kind `(k -> Type) -> k -> Type`: it takes *two* type parameters, one of them a type constructor.

The following (useless) type fits your instance: `D1 (MetaData "" "" "" True) Proxy`, because [`Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html#t:Proxy) has kind `k -> Type`. But you can't use `undef2` with something of type `Proxy z`, whatever the `z`:

```
ghci> :t undef2 (undefined :: Proxy Int)

<interactive>:1:9: error:
* Couldn't match kind `forall {k}. k -> Type'
                 with `(Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type'
```